# Windows terminal server becomes unresponsive

Tags: resource-usage

I have a problem where a Windows terminal server sometimes becomes unresponsive for like 10 minutes at a time.

During this time, users that were already logged in can't open applications, any application. They also can't log out, they basically can't do anything.

On the other hand, users that weren't logged in via RDP cannot log in at all, there's no special error, it's as if the service isn't up.

At first I thought maybe it had something to do with server resources but I checked both our monitoring solution and perfmon reports, both showed normal results without spikes, around 70% at the highest.

What else could I look at? What would you do next?

Comment: Check for interesting messages in the Event Viewer; test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Update:

The server is a VM, and although I didn't see high CPU usage in perfmon or in my monitoring solution.

The host monitor shows that the server VM has a very high CPU usage.

Comment: Please do the above checks.